# adding more table rows depending on the first filtered result with mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy

Using mariadb version 10.5.15 (and SQLAlchemy with python 3.9).
After filtering the following table with e.g. count == 3 i would get the rows with id's

2, 3, 4, 7 and 12.

Then for each of these rows i want to add every row (of the same table) if row 2, 3, 4, 7 or 12 have the same group_id (excluding null) but a different group_leader  value. So i would like to add

(same group_id, not same group_leader)
1, 3 (coming from id 2)
5    (coming from id 4)
10   (coming from id 7 and only id 10, because group_leader  must be different)

| id | count | group_id | group_leader |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | null |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 2 | null |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | null |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | null |
| 8 | 1 | 3 | null |
| 9 | 2 | 3 | null |
| 10 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 11 | 5 | null | null |
| 12 | 3 | null | null |

Is it possible to first do the select...from...where... and then add these other rows or do i first have to do something like join?

This is the actual example:

```
def query_positions(position_filter: dict):
    result = db.session.query(Positions).join(
    ProjectCrafts, Positions.project_craft_id == ProjectCrafts.project_craft_id).join(
        Projects, Positions.project_id == Projects.project_id
    )
    if "firm_id" in position_filter:
        result = result.filter(Positions.firm_id == position_filter["firm_id"])
    if "craft" in position_filter:
        result = result.filter(ProjectCrafts.craft == position_filter["craft"])
    if "craft_name" in position_filter:
        result = result.filter(ProjectCrafts.craft_name == position_filter["craft_name"])

    positions1 = aliased(Positions)
    result = result.join(positions1, Positions.is_parent == 1, Positions.family_id == positions1.family_id).join(
        Positions.family_id == positions1.family_id)
positions = result.all()
return positions
```

The problem comes after the `positions1 = aliased(Positions)` and i get this error

...

> in _join_determine_implicit_left_side
> raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError( sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to
> <AliasedInsp at 0x7fabd1ad30; Positions(Positions)>. Please use the
> .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as
> providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve
> the ambiguity.

Comment: Your tree structure implementation is not easy to understand, can you add some more information about the fields in the table, what they are used for and a final result set you are trying to get? At the moment, to get the data you want, it looks like you will have to use a recursive CTE. It might be good for you to read more about different SQL tree structures, such as nested sets.

Comment: The naming was misleading. It's not a tree (only a tree of depth 1)

Comment: My actual case is more complex, but i thought an answer to this question would be enough

Comment: "After filtering the following table with e.g. count == 3 i would get the rows with id's 1, 3, 4, 7 and 12." => I see only IDs 2, 4, 7 and 12 with count 3

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem? @Timo

Comment: I can also post the table schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the filtered table on the count_ with the original table, where you impose the two main conditions:

- "*group_id*" are the same
- "*group_leader*" are different

Then apply a `UNION` between the two result sets, optionally followed by and `ORDER BY` clause to order your values on the id.

Given that NULL values and NON-NULL values are neither equal nor different, a way to compare them is transforming NULL values to `-1` (assuming this value cannot be employed by "*group_leader*" values) using the `COALESCE` function.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM tab WHERE count_ = 3
)
SELECT tab.* 
FROM       tab
INNER JOIN cte
        ON tab.group_id = cte.group_id
       AND COALESCE(tab.group_leader, -1) <> COALESCE(cte.group_leader, -1)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rRAow412pCfw2bWwzzVToy/0).

Comment: This looks good and im trying to transform this example to my case (since yesturday). It feels easier to do that without SQLAlchemy, so im just building the sql command. 
I am pretty sure, that this answer answers my question, even thou i still have errors that i don't understand. Is the way to go, that i open a new question and this question here gets closed?

Comment: What I would do is opening a new question if the issue regards sqlalchemy. If the problem regards the SQL code, I would leave it open. But really in this case it is really up to you.

Comment: None of both. I assume you mean your SQL code by "the SQL code".
I might open a new question if i can't figure it out.